# Integrate Github Actions with Playwright for multiple environment

Tags: playwright, github-actions-runners

I want to execute my test script on multiple environment using the same code and same workflow over Github actions.

I am not able to pass the environment variable to the npx command.

Code I am using :

```
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      Environment:
        type: choice
        description: 'Account URL which you want to test'
        required: true
        default: 'STG'

name: Run playwright
         env:
            URL = ${{github.event.inputs.Environment}}
        id: runPlaywright
        run: |
            xvfb-run -- npx playwright test tests/IAM_Sanity/SignUp-SignIn
```

In Playwright :

I am using baseURl in  playwright.config.js. and accessing this element using process.env.URL.

in my local, I am able to use it by running $env.URL = STG

Please suggest some solution